# Meteor - Excel File Upload without storing file on db

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like the user to be able to upload a file through a file input and the client would send the file to the server and the server would parse the file without storing it in the database, is this possible?

Something like this:

```
    'change input': function(e, t) {
        let file = e.target.files[0];
        let extension = file.name.split(".").pop();
        if (['xlsb', 'xls', 'xlsx'].indexOf(extension) < 0) {
          Notify.show("error", `Invalid file extension`);
          return false;
        } else {
          Meteor.call("upload.factual.achievements", file, function(err, res){
            if(err){
              Notify.show("error", `There was an error : ${error.reason}.`);
            } else {
...
            }
          });

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly recommend using a package like `ostrio:files` https://files.veliov.com/

This will store your files to the filesystem by default and retain a pointer to the location in a Collection that you can query to return the image from the filesystem later